# Why is data from my React context loading inconsistently until I refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am using a React context to store user data upon login. Right now I am only dealing with two pieces of data received from the API: the token received upon authentication, and the user ID.  These data are stored in the context, as well as the sessionStorage to be present in case of a page reload.

On my login page, this fetch takes place upon submitting the log in form:

```js
  const userCtx = useContext(UserContext);
...
    fetch('/api/tokens', opts)
        .then(res => {
          return res.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
          userCtx.setToken(data.token);
          sessionStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
          userCtx.setId(data.user_id);
          sessionStorage.setItem("user_id", data.user_id);
        })
```

where opts are fetch options.

My context file looks like:

```js
import {createContext, useState} from 'react'

const UserContext = createContext();

export function UserContextProvider(props) {
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const context = {
    id: sessionStorage.getItem("user_id"),
    token: sessionStorage.getItem("token"),
    setId: setId,
    setToken: setToken,
    logOut: logOut
  }

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={context}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
  
}

export default UserContext
```

And the UserContextProvider wraps the entire app in `index.js`.

I am noticing some inconsistent loading of the `token` and `id` parts of the context. If I use context in a component (i.e., `const user = useContext(UserContext)`) and `console.log()` `user.token` and `user.id` simultaneously, only the `user.token` loads, while `user.id` is `null`. If I refresh the page however, `user.id` successfully logs.  What should I do so that they appear simultaneously upon logging in a user, without refreshing the page?

[Aside: I recognize my code is potentially insecure and currently does not capture all aspects of a login session]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was a classic case of me not setting the state. I happened to be addressing the wrong JSON key and as a result the state was not getting updated.